# Make sure, touchscreen works on HP Pavilion x360

Tags: hp, 18.10, touchscreen, hp-pavilion

This machine came with Windows 10 which I can not stand. I want to install ubuntu 18.04 or newer but I also want to make sure that I get to keep a particular feature which is the **touchscreen** capability. Can I keep this and how? I do not wish to keep Windows 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: I use it with a dell touch screen and it works great so you ought to be fine!

Answer (score 0):

Normaly, you will automatically have a functioanlly touch screen.
If you want to be sure, you can first **Try Ubuntu**.
You can follow [this](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop) insctruction up to [Step 3](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#2), there you can choose **Try Ubunut**.

As long as you dont press **Continue** on [Step 6](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#6) you can just reboot and nothing has changed on your laptop.